# How to append values from an Array only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, express, socket.io

Am currently appending values into a table based on the number of calls stored in an array.

My problem is it keeps printing off the previous value along with the new one. I have tried a couple of things and its just not happening for me.Even getting it pulling out value in real time would work too I think but no joy there yet, as currently it ill only show the value if I reload the page.

**Brief idea of my issue E.G:**
1 Value in the array: Works fine.
2 Values adds previous value and the new one in the same box and the rest works accordingly.

Anyone any ideas?

**test.js**

Where I am appending the data found in the array, ave tried in and outside the for loop *Optimistically* that it would stop appending the values more than once.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var socket = io.connect();
    var $sip = $('#sip');
    socket.on('sip', function (data) {
        var sip = '';
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            sip += data[i]
        if(sip){
        $sip.append('<tr>\
                                    <td>' + sip + '</td>\
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" data-on="Voice" data-off="Muted" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"></td>\
                                    <td><button class="btn btn-default kick" id="kick" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="submit">Kick</button></td>\
                                    </tr>');
        }
        else{
            $sip.append('Currently no extensions');
        }
        }

    });
});
```

**app.js**

Where my ARI Client and Server side stuff is, the array being accessed is call chanArr and is located at the top of the page and being called and emitted at the bottom via updateSip function.

```
    var chanArr = [];
    var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

 function stasisStart(event, channel) {
          bridge.addChannel({
            channel : channel.id
          }, function (err) {
            var id = chanArr.push(channel.name)
              console.log("User: " + channel.name);
            if (err) {
              throw err;
            }
}

    //Socket.io logic here
    server.listen(3009, function () {
      console.log('listening on *:3009');
    });

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.sendfile(__dirname + "/testPage.html");
    });

    io.sockets.on('connection', function () {
      updateSip();
    });

    function updateSip() {
      io.sockets.emit('sip', chanArr);
    }
```

**testpage.html**

The table body with the id of sip  is where am appending the rows.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Chat with socket.io and node.js</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
                <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">   
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <div class="secondary-bridge">
                            <h3 class="conf-head">Conference call:</h3>
                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Extension</th>
                                        <th>Mute</th>
                                        <th>Kick</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id ="sip">
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
                        <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
                            <script src="/js/test.js"></script>
                        </body>
                    </html>
```

EDIT: When I use.append and .html.

.append
[image: .append]

.html
[image: .html]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the value of `sip` after you append it in this case before the loop moves to the next iteration.

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    sip += data[i]
    if(sip){
        $sip.append('<tr>\
                                    <td>' + sip + '</td>\
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" data-on="Voice" data-off="Muted" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"></td>\
                                    <td><button class="btn btn-default kick" id="kick" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="submit">Kick</button></td>\
                                    </tr>');
    }
    else{
            $sip.append('Currently no extensions');
        }
   sip = ''; // this is where you reset the variable value!
}
```

Comment: I have already looked at the link to see if that was the issue but the problem is currently still there, I have updated the question with what happens when I use both.

Comment: @Studento919 please see the updated answer. I think I understood your question now.

Comment: I am so annoyed at myself for not even thinking of resetting the variable value. Thanks for the assist :)

Comment: that's okay, it happens! also make it a point to post only the relevant code in the question, people hardly take a look at such long code snippets :)